# How does the UploadObjectAsync() method work?

Tags: c#, .net, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/documen-management/upload-document/

I am following the tutorial above to upload a file into a BIM 360 folder through Autodesk Forge. I have reached **Step 6: Upload the File to the Storage Object** and I am trying to use the method **UploadObjectAsync()** to upload a file but I am getting an error stating: **error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.Web.HttpInputStream'** and I am unsure how to fix this.

Am I using the wrong method or there something I am missing in the code? Below is the method I am using on .NET.

```
HttpPostedFile file = req.Files[0];
ObjectsApi objectsApi = new ObjectsApi();
dynamic objects = await objectsApi.UploadObjectAsync(bucketKey, objectName, file.ContentLength, file.InputStream);
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I see you assign the input stream to `body` but you never use it. You then use `file.InputStream` again. Maybe you have advanced the stream to the end by assigning it to `body` and that is causing an issue.

Comment: Sorry I was testing out that code and will edit the question above to remove that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use the underlying stream of a `StreamReader` from the file to upload, instead of the raw `InputStream` from multipart form:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileSavePath))
{
    await objects.UploadObjectAsync(bucketKey, objectName,(int)streamReader.BaseStream.Length, streamReader.BaseStream, "application/octet-stream");
    ...
}
```

Given how the `UploadObjectAsync` and its chained method `UploadObjectAsyncWith`(code [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/24d9da4a1be19aef38c088a1a854de4e45c1efb5/src/Autodesk.Forge/Api/ObjectsApi.cs#L2940)) is implemented you'd better saved the posted file and then upload it instead of piping streams. See an example [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/data.management-csharp-sample/blob/b3ab49a41f6e20161d0c5d707f2e56bc7e3e27ad/forgeSample/Controllers/DataManagementController.cs#L324).

Comment: Thanks after using a similar method to code above, it works now.