# Cant extract metadata properties of large files

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a RVT file which is around 200MB. When I upload the object using forge SDK `(ObjectsApi.UploadObjectAsync())`, I got time-out error multiple times but somehow later on it uploaded the object and extracted manifest.

However, while extracting `modelViewMetadataProperties` of each sheet, it throwed `URN is too big to extract` error and I couldnt process it.

How can I upload the object and extract modelViewMetadataProperties smoothly with large files?

SDK version: `Assembly Autodesk.Forge, Version=1.9.0.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload large files, I would advise you to use [ObjectApi#UploadChunk](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/ObjectsApi.md#uploadchunk) instead. Here is an example demonstrating how to use it: https://github.com/yiskang/ForgeResumableUploadProgressDemo/blob/master/ForgeResumableUploadProgressDemo/Program.cs#L93

Regarding the properties issue, please follow Alex's suggestion to add the `forceget` parameter and set it to true. Here is its [declaration](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/7c5317aafdaf1407de6d7bd773e24e4e80b50204/src/Autodesk.Forge/Api/DerivativesApi.cs#L237):

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Returns a list of properties for each object in an object tree. Properties are returned according to object ID and do not follow a hierarchical structure.  The following image displays a typical list of properties for a Revit object:  ![](https://developer.doc.autodesk.com/bPlouYTd/7/_images/Properties.png)  To call this endpoint you need to first call the [GET {urn}/metadata](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET) endpoint, which returns a list of model view (metadata) IDs for a design input model. Select a model view (metadata) ID to use when calling the Get Properties endpoint.  Note that you can only get properties from a design input file that was previously translated into an SVF file. 
/// </remarks>
/// <exception cref="Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException">Thrown when fails to make API call</exception>
/// <param name="urn">The Base64 (URL Safe) encoded design URN </param>
/// <param name="guid">Unique model view ID. Call [GET {urn}/metadata](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET) to get the ID </param>
/// <param name="acceptEncoding">If specified with &#x60;gzip&#x60; or &#x60;*&#x60;, content will be compressed and returned in a GZIP format.  (optional)</param>
/// <param name="objectid">Object id which you want to query properties for.</param>
/// <param name="xAdsForce">If true - force retrieve the object tree even though it failed to be retrieved or got timeout (got 404 with error message) previously.</param>
/// <param name="forceget">If true - To force get the large resource even if it exceeded the expected maximum length (20 MB).</param>
/// <returns>Metadata</returns>
/*Metadata*/
dynamic GetModelviewProperties (string urn, string guid, string acceptEncoding = null, List<int> objectIds = null, bool xAdsForce = false, bool forceget = false);
```

Here is an example of its usage:

```
derivativeApi.GetModelviewProperties( urn, guid, null, null, false, true );
```

Answer (score 0):

For the time-out error, this link may help [How does the UploadObjectAsync() method work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854072/how-does-the-uploadobjectasync-method-work)

About the metadata properties, the documentation says that you can query with `forceget` parameter to `true` if the resource exceed `20mb`. This option should be available in the SDK method.
[URN Metadata Get Properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/)